# Manage Client PCs with windows 10 updates via Samba

Tags: active-directory, samba, windows-10

is it possible to use a Samba server to manage a Lan with about 10 PCs (Windows) in such a way that I can control the Windows updates? If so, is Active Directory necessary for it?
I can only find (a lot of information) how to configure samba file servers and so on but this is not my purpose, isn't it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I have not tried it, Nitrobit Update Server runs on linux and allows you to manage Microsoft Updates on Linux. It claims to be a replacement for Windows Update Server (WSUS), meaning that it will allow you to approve, decline, and deploy Windows updates as well as generate reports, etc. It can be installed via RPM or Debian based package managers and can integrate with existing samba server deployments.

http://www.nitrobit.com/updateserver.html

Comment: Sure, sorry, wanted to test it but I guess this will take a longer time of period. But the software promises to be the one :)